# Most appropriate global variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that I execute when I press a button.
I don't want the user to execute the function twice in a row. So I used a `window` variable.
I did:

```
function a() {  
  if(window.infunction != undefined || window.infunction != null) {  
       return;  
  }  
  window.infunction = 'true';    
  //do stuff  
}
```

Somewhere else (in another button press) I reset:  `window.infunction = undefined`

Is this the proper way to use global variables (at least for my needs)?

Comment: Sure, but you can avoid globals if you just wrap everything in a function. Btw, `window.infunction != undefined` will be `true` for both `undefined` and `null`. No need to explicitly test for `null`.

Comment: Why is `'true'` a string? Why not simply an actual boolean value `true`?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no good reason to use global variables for this. It's easy enough to just wrap all your code in a function to avoid polluting the global namespace:

```
(function() {
    //all your code here
})();
```

But I think a better solution would be to remove the event handler upon clicking the button instead. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<button id="click_me">Click me</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function click_function() {
    alert('You clicked the button with ID ' + this.id);
}

function click_listener() {
    click_function.call(this);
    this.removeEventListener('click', click_listener);
}

document.getElementById('click_me').addEventListener('click', click_listener);
```

---

---

Alternatively, some JS libraries make it easy to assign a handler that will only fire once.
In fact, I highly recommend this: you won't have to type nearly as much code. For example, when using jQuery you can just write:

```
$('#click_me').one('click', function() {
    alert('You clicked the button with ID ' + this.id);
});
```

This does the same thing as the above code, except it's compatible with more browsers, including older versions of IE.

Comment: How do I avoid the function being called twice?

Comment: @Cratylus updated my answer, check it out. when you click the button once, you'll see the alert, but clicking it again does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Functions are objects. They can have properties like any other objects:

```
function a(){
    if (a.executed) return;
    a.executed = true;

    //do stuff
}
```

As @Ian mentioned in his comment you can easy make the function reusable. It can be advantage as well as a downside of this approach.

And as @Dave said it can be achieved with closure:

```
var a = (function (){
    var executed = false;

    return function (){
        if (executed) return;
        executed = true;

        //do stuff
    }
})();
```

Comment: or just define a scoped variable inside the function (setting variables on a function is a rather odd thing to do if it isn't behaving like an object)

Comment: In the case of anonymous functions you can use `arguments.callee.executed` too ;)

Comment: @Kolink Is not arguments.callee deprecated? Or you are being sarcastic? :)

Comment: `arguments.callee` is deprecated in strict mode

Comment: This is a little sloppy. You can easily clean it up and make it actually (re)usable. http://jsfiddle.net/KXapu/

Comment: @Ian so making it reusable can be an advantage as well

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button or hide it so the user is not confused why the button does nothing after the first click.

```
function a(e) {
     e = e || window.event;
     e = e.target || e.srcElement;  
    // disable element
    e.disabled = true;
}
```

<s>You should just unbind the event instead.</s>

```
function a(e) {  
    // unbind the event
    e = e || window.event;
    e = e.target || e.srcElement;
    e.onclick = null;
}
```

Comment: Yea, I can see why you would downvote this, better to use a global.

Comment: why is that? i would *never* do this with a global.

Comment: @sgroves - you must not be familiar with sarcasm.

Comment: sorry, tired :P upvoted because this is definitely a fine answer.

Comment: @Gabe:My function does not have a parameter. What is `ctrl`?

Comment: It's a reference to the element that fired the click...how about you binding the event in the first place?

Comment: @Gabe:`onclick=myfunction()`

Comment: Updated the answer, `e` is the `event`.

Comment: What is the reason to set `e.disabled` if every time `e` is a brand new object?

Comment: @claustrofob, it only get's called once. So there wouldn't be any subsequent events fired since its disabled.

Comment: @Gabe:But where in the answer code do we check if we should run the function code or not?

Comment: @Cratylus - it just won't run at all, the button is disabled after running the first time.